# Reloading Vaadin UIs without restarting the application

Tags: vaadin, jrebel, spring-loaded, vaadin8

I am developing a Vaadin 8 UI. At the moment, each time I modify the UI, I have to restart my application.

Is there a better way? I have tried attaching the Java debugger and using IntelliJ's Reload Changed Classes feature, but the hotswap fails.

I have seen mention of [JRebel](https://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/) in the context of Vaadin, but I can't afford that - [Spring Loaded](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-loaded) seems to be [another option](https://github.com/Artur-/spring-boot-loaded-vaadin). Is there anything else?

Comment: Depends on your toolchain. When you for example use Netbeans with a local tomcat/ee, you can make small code changes direct beeing taken over with no reload. But on structure changes you will have redeploy the app

Answer (score 1):

http://www.hermansjavablog.eu/programming/definitive-guide-vaadin-7-maven-tomcat-intellij-idea-hotswap-deployment/ seems quite promising. Maybe there are some options you missed..

**EDITED**

In Eclipse I tried now with SpringLoaded http://blog.netgloo.com/2014/05/21/hot-swapping-in-spring-boot-with-eclipse-sts/ and amazingly it works.

In Intellij http://tomaszjanek.pl/blog/2015/02/03/hot-reloading-in-spring-boot-with-spring-loaded/ might help to achieve the same.

Comment: I'd also mention devtools (http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-devtools.html) for those who happen to use Spring Boot.

Answer (score 0):

We use Jetty in development and have configured hot deployment to it. Applications state will be lost, but during development it's most probably exactly what you want. http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.4.x/hot-deployment.html